# Editor template values differ in format than Index Template MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

After going through a lot of blogs and solutions on stackoverflow on how to get the values in Editor template according to the needed format in MVC 5, I am putting forward my question.
On my index page I display decimal values, e.g. 43.345.
However, on the Editor template the value displayed would be 43.34.

I tried adding the right notation in the model "ApplyFormatInEditMode = true".

The way I am rendering the value in Editor Mode (view) is
@html.EditorFor(m =>m.value) ;

Comment: Have you also set `DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"`?

Comment: I have set it to DataFormatString = "{0:#,0.000}"

Comment: Are you wanting different formats for the edit mode (2 decimals) and display mode (3 decimals)?

Comment: I want the same number as displayed on the Index page. Currently the Editor template is rounding the 3 decimal number to 2 decimals which is unpleasant in my scenario.

Comment: That's not the default behaviour (just tested it and both `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` show 3 decimal places - I'm using MVC 4 but I don't believe this has changed in MVC 5). Do you have a custom editor template that may be overriding the default

Comment: Thanks Stephen. You are right ! the editor template was overridden. Default method shows the 3 decimals!!